# Maven artifact in Artifactory cannot be found

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

The situation: we have a Jenkins job that builds a jar and publishes it to Artifactory, in a custom maven repo. The pom and maven-metadata.xml files are generated, and Anonymous has been given read access to the repository. I've added the repository to my maven settings.xml and verified that maven sees the profile containing the artifactory settings. Despite all this, artifactory still won't resolve the dependency, even though everything looks like it should work. We're just integrating Artifactory into our build process, so we don't have any Artifactory expertise, and Google hasn't turned up anything helpful so far.

UPDATE: I located the original problem - Artifactory couldn't locate the jar in the repo because it wanted an exact match to the jar name, including the timestamp, which is useless for maven. Having fixed that, I'm now running into a further problem.
From the Artifactory log:

> 2017-11-17 10:09:15,838 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] [WARN ]
>   (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:437) - jcenter: Error in getting information for
>   'org/tiaacref/ted/digital-metrics-commons/1.1-SNAPSHOT/digital-metrics-commons-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
>   (Failed retrieving resource from
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/tiaacref/ted/digital-metrics-commons/1.1-SNAPSHOT/digital-metrics-commons-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:
>   Unknown host - jcenter.bintray.com).

Why is Artifactory going to an external URL to try to resolve an artifact contained in a local repository???

Comment: your job's logs would be good to start off with, maybe better run them with -X to trace all that maven does.

Comment: I did that - I always get the same result - Could not resolve dependency followed by the jar information. Everything up to that point looks good.

Comment: Can you share the entries from Artifactory's request.log + artifactory.log files?

Comment: Additional: I added the custom repository to libs-releasse and libs-snapshot so it can be resolved using one of those virtual repositories. And while I can see the files directly using my web browser to look at the repository, maven still complains about not being able to resolve the dependency,